# AJAX transfer large amount of data using $_POST method

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I would like to transfer a large amount of text to the server using AJAX. I would like to attach this text using the POST method, but I get the following error:

request failed: URI too long (longer than 8190)

My javascript code:

```
function loadXMLDoc(data) {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.mydomain.com/test2.php?blob=" + data, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

My php code:

```
$dataraw = $_GET["blob"];

file_put_contents('/path/to/my/file/newfile.txt', $dataraw);

echo 'file saved';
```

Comment: you're using `"POST"` in JS method but you're referring to `$_GET` in php. just want to point out.

Answer (score 3):

You should change this

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.mydomain.com/test2.php?blob=" + data,true);  
xmlhttp.send();
```

to this:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.mydomain.com/test2.php", true);   
var payload = "blob=" + data;
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");  
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", payload.length);
xmlhttp.send(payload);
```

In POST, parameters should go in the body of the message, not the URL.

At the same time, you should expect the parameters on the server-side in $_POST - that's where the body parameter will end up in in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I made the changes as you described but it didn't work. If I comment out the three setRequestHeader lines the php script runs. But I'm not able to pass the payload to the php file. Yes I did change the $_GET to $_POST in the php code.

Comment: My server error log file indicates: Undefined index: blob in (path to file)

Comment: Got it! In your example you had http.setRequestHeader, when I changed these three lines to xmlhttp.setRequestHeader it worked perfect. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't add post-data to the URL. Please check this link to find an example of a post-request:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```